# Whats the difference between these enum in C?

Tags: c, struct, enums, typedef

New to C so Im getting confused here.

I have three different enum

```
enum Space{STAR = 6, PLANET, SUN =3, EARTH =5, PLUTO};

typedef enum {STAR = 6, PLANET, SUN =3, EARTH =5, PLUTO}System;

typedef enum Space{STAR = 6, PLANET, SUN =3, EARTH =5, PLUTO}System;
```

what exactly are the differences between these three?

I know they are an ordered set of variables with type int
so PLANET = 7, PLUTO = 6, etc.

But ive tried printing the values, but it seems like they all work the same.

```
printf("%d", PLANET);
```

Comment: The enum contains looks to be same, it's only how they are defined (type and named / unnamed).

Comment: @SouravGhosh sorry, so whats the difference in terms of definition?

Comment: You got your answers below already. :)

Comment: Just to be clear, these are type declarations that create new types. No *variables* are being defined, no run-time memory is being used to hold these (unless you use them in the code).

Answer (score 7):

This may seem strange or confusing, but: structs, unions, and enums can end up having two (or more) different names in C.

The first and in some sense more basic name is usually called a "tag".  It's the name in your first example:

```
enum Space {STAR = 6, PLANET, SUN = 3, EARTH = 5, PLUTO};
```

We've created a new enumeration (which is actually a new type), describing 5 enumeration constants, and we've given it the tag name "`Space`".

A tag name is not global -- the word "`Space`" is not quite enough to uniquely identify this new type we've created.  If we want to declare a variable that can hold values of this new enumeration type, we have to repeat the `enum` keyword when we do so:

```
enum Space spacevar;
```

If we tried to just say

```
Space spacevar;
```

the compiler would complain, because `Space` is not a type name, it's just a tag name.

(It's sort of like the name "Washington" in U.S. geography.  Does it refer to the state of Washington in the Pacific Northwest, or the city of Washington, D.C.?  We always need a bit more information, an additional word or abbreviation, to be sure.)

And then we come to typedefs.  A typedef does create a new type name (for an existing type).  And the typedef can "contain" a fair amount of information.  If we say

```
typedef int myint;
```

then `myint` is just a synonym for `int`.  But if we say

```
typedef int *intptr;
```

then `intptr` means "pointer to `int`" and it "contains" the `*`; we can later say

```
intptr p1, p2;
```

and we get two pointers.  Similarly, if we say

```
typedef enum Space System;
```

then `System` is a new type name that means "`enum Space`" and it "contains" the keyword `enum`.  Later we can declare another variable of the enumeration type

```
System spacevar2;
```

This is just the same as

```
enum Space spacevar2;
```

except that when we use `System` to declare the `spacevar2` variable, we don't have to repeat that `enum` keyword.

So now we can go back to your second and third examples.  Your third example,

```
typedef enum Space {STAR = 6, PLANET, SUN = 3, EARTH = 5, PLUTO} System;
```

declares the tag name `Space` and the type name `System` at the same time, on the same line.  It's just as if you'd said

```
enum Space {STAR = 6, PLANET, SUN = 3, EARTH = 5, PLUTO} System;
typedef enum Space System;
```

on two lines.

And then your second example

```
typedef enum {STAR = 6, PLANET, SUN = 3, EARTH = 5, PLUTO} System;
```

creates the same new type, except it gives it *only* a type name, not a tag name.  This gives you an enum type where you can declare new variables only using the type name form:

```
System spacevar3;
```

In this case, you can't say

```
enum ??? spacevar3
```

because you haven't declared a tag name that could go in the `???` spot.

But in the end, no matter which form you use and how you've declared your enumeration variables, you can use them all in the same way.  You can say

```
spaceval = STAR;
```

and

```
spaceval2 = PLANET;
```

and

```
spaceval3 = SUN;
```

There's not any different way you have to use the variables depending on which kind of name (tag name or type name) you used to define them.

Comment: Still a little confusing but this really helps! Appreciate the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

```
enum Space{STAR = 6, PLANET, SUN =3, EARTH =5, PLUTO};
```

Named enum (name is Space). Use `enum Space varname`.

```
typedef enum {STAR = 6, PLANET, SUN =3, EARTH =5, PLUTO}System;
```

Unnamed enum typedef to System. Use `System varname`.

```
typedef enum Space{STAR = 6, PLANET, SUN =3, EARTH =5, PLUTO}System;
```

Named enum (name is Space) and typedef to System. Use `System varname` or `enum Space varname`.

Answer (score 2):

Enums, structs, and unions may have a *tag name* - it's how you can refer to that particular type later on.

```
enum Space { ... }; // defines the enumeration type
enum Space someVariable; // create an instance of that type
```

`enum Space` is the name of the type.

You can define the type with the tag name *and* declare an instance of that type in the same declaration:

```
enum Space { ... } someVariable; // defines the type, tag name, and an instance
enum Space anotherVariable; // define another instance using the tag name
```

The tag name is optional when you're declaring an instance at the same time as you are defining the type:

```
enum { ... } someVariable; // tag name not necessary here
```

However, you will not be able to create another variable of that same type.  You would have to repeat the type definition<sup>1</sup>, and each new instance would be of a distinct type, even though the types are structurally identical.

You can create an *alias* for the type using the `typedef` facility:

```
typedef enum Space { ... } Space;
```

`Space` is an alias for *type* `enum Space`, so you can create a new instance using either

```
Space someVar;
```

or

```
enum Space someVar;
```

Again, the tag name is optional, so you can also create the alias as

```
typedef enum { ... } Space;
```

Since `Space` is an *alias* for the enumeration type, you *can* create multiple instances without the tag name:

```
Space foo;
Space bar;
```

In this case you are not *repeating* the definition (as you would by writing `enum { ... } foo; enum { ... } bar;`), you're referring to the same definition.

Tag names occupy a different *name space* from other identifiers, so you can have both `enum Space` and `Space` at the same time.  The tag name is *disambiguated* from the variable or typedef name by the `enum` keyword.

For reference, C has four distinct name spaces:

- tag names for enums, structs, and unions (disambiguated by the presence of the `enum`, `struct`, or `union` keyword);
- struct and union member names (disambiguated by the presence of the `.` or `->` member selection operators);
- label names (disambiguated by a trailing `:` or a `goto` keyword);
- all other identifiers (variable names, function names, enumeration constants, etc,).

---

1. With structs and unions, anyway - I'm not sure you can repeat an enum definition, since all enumeration constants are part of the same name space.

Answer (score 1):

The first create a named enumeration.

The second creates an unnamed enumeration but defines a typename (type alias).

The third creates a named enumeration *and* a typename.

The actual values of the enumeration constants are the same in all three.

Comment: Would the way you use it be the same or completely different?

Comment: @iLoveUnix With the named enumerations you can do e.g. `enum Space some_variable;`. This is not possible with the unnamed variant. For the ones with typenames defined you can do `System some_variable;` instead, and it would mean just the same. Once you have defined a variable of the enumeration, then it doesn't matter anymore since they will all be the same.